# Winform control becomes child of other control, as opposed to being added to the form.

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have three panels all stacked on top of each other in the same location in a windows form application. 
Each time I add another panel on top it becomes a child of the previous panel. This means each panel cannot be shown independently, ie, to show panel 2 I must first show panel1 (the parent). I'm fairly sure this is what is happening. However I need to be able to call panel2.show(), whilst panel 1 is hidden.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Instead of dragging and dropping the pannel on the existing panel you should put panel somewhere else on the form and set its location property manually from  properties window.

Comment: have you considered using a tab control instead...kinda sounds like you are manually engineering one

Answer (score 0):

This is a WinForms designer issue. You can either try moving the panels around and set the position in the properties or enter code behind and set the parent-child relationships manually.

Answer (score 0):

basically don't just drag and drop panels on top of each other. Try to programmatically code their locations. Look for this kind of code in your **Form.Designer.cs** `this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.panel3);` and delete them.

Add all your panels in the form part which is supposed to be at the bottom.

```
this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
this.Controls.Add(this.panel3);
```

This should be able to put all panels as form children.